# multiple svg not properly rendering in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, browser

I am trying to add svg in my html page.
http://jsfiddle.net/5p0v11rt/

**step 1** : I first took svg image of (a+b)^2 and inserted in html page
         this svg code rendered successfully in my html page.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="33pt" height="13pt" viewBox="0 0 33 13" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.296875 2.390625 C 3.296875 2.359375 3.296875 2.34375 3.125 2.171875 C 1.890625 0.921875 1.5625 -0.96875 1.5625 -2.5 C 1.5625 -4.234375 1.9375 -5.96875 3.171875 -7.203125 C 3.296875 -7.328125 3.296875 -7.34375 3.296875 -7.375 C 3.296875 -7.453125 3.265625 -7.484375 3.203125 -7.484375 C 3.09375 -7.484375 2.203125 -6.796875 1.609375 -5.53125 C 1.109375 -4.4375 0.984375 -3.328125 0.984375 -2.5 C 0.984375 -1.71875 1.09375 -0.515625 1.640625 0.625 C 2.25 1.84375 3.09375 2.5 3.203125 2.5 C 3.265625 2.5 3.296875 2.46875 3.296875 2.390625 Z M 3.296875 2.390625 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.078125 -2.296875 L 6.859375 -2.296875 C 7 -2.296875 7.1875 -2.296875 7.1875 -2.5 C 7.1875 -2.6875 7 -2.6875 6.859375 -2.6875 L 4.078125 -2.6875 L 4.078125 -5.484375 C 4.078125 -5.625 4.078125 -5.8125 3.875 -5.8125 C 3.671875 -5.8125 3.671875 -5.625 3.671875 -5.484375 L 3.671875 -2.6875 L 0.890625 -2.6875 C 0.75 -2.6875 0.5625 -2.6875 0.5625 -2.5 C 0.5625 -2.296875 0.75 -2.296875 0.890625 -2.296875 L 3.671875 -2.296875 L 3.671875 0.5 C 3.671875 0.640625 3.671875 0.828125 3.875 0.828125 C 4.078125 0.828125 4.078125 0.640625 4.078125 0.5 Z M 4.078125 -2.296875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-3">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.875 -2.5 C 2.875 -3.265625 2.765625 -4.46875 2.21875 -5.609375 C 1.625 -6.828125 0.765625 -7.484375 0.671875 -7.484375 C 0.609375 -7.484375 0.5625 -7.4375 0.5625 -7.375 C 0.5625 -7.34375 0.5625 -7.328125 0.75 -7.140625 C 1.734375 -6.15625 2.296875 -4.578125 2.296875 -2.5 C 2.296875 -0.78125 1.9375 0.96875 0.703125 2.21875 C 0.5625 2.34375 0.5625 2.359375 0.5625 2.390625 C 0.5625 2.453125 0.609375 2.5 0.671875 2.5 C 0.765625 2.5 1.671875 1.8125 2.25 0.546875 C 2.765625 -0.546875 2.875 -1.65625 2.875 -2.5 Z M 2.875 -2.5 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.71875 -3.765625 C 3.53125 -4.140625 3.25 -4.40625 2.796875 -4.40625 C 1.640625 -4.40625 0.40625 -2.9375 0.40625 -1.484375 C 0.40625 -0.546875 0.953125 0.109375 1.71875 0.109375 C 1.921875 0.109375 2.421875 0.0625 3.015625 -0.640625 C 3.09375 -0.21875 3.453125 0.109375 3.921875 0.109375 C 4.28125 0.109375 4.5 -0.125 4.671875 -0.4375 C 4.828125 -0.796875 4.96875 -1.40625 4.96875 -1.421875 C 4.96875 -1.53125 4.875 -1.53125 4.84375 -1.53125 C 4.75 -1.53125 4.734375 -1.484375 4.703125 -1.34375 C 4.53125 -0.703125 4.359375 -0.109375 3.953125 -0.109375 C 3.671875 -0.109375 3.65625 -0.375 3.65625 -0.5625 C 3.65625 -0.78125 3.671875 -0.875 3.78125 -1.3125 C 3.890625 -1.71875 3.90625 -1.828125 4 -2.203125 L 4.359375 -3.59375 C 4.421875 -3.875 4.421875 -3.890625 4.421875 -3.9375 C 4.421875 -4.109375 4.3125 -4.203125 4.140625 -4.203125 C 3.890625 -4.203125 3.75 -3.984375 3.71875 -3.765625 Z M 3.078125 -1.1875 C 3.015625 -1 3.015625 -0.984375 2.875 -0.8125 C 2.4375 -0.265625 2.03125 -0.109375 1.75 -0.109375 C 1.25 -0.109375 1.109375 -0.65625 1.109375 -1.046875 C 1.109375 -1.546875 1.421875 -2.765625 1.65625 -3.234375 C 1.96875 -3.8125 2.40625 -4.1875 2.8125 -4.1875 C 3.453125 -4.1875 3.59375 -3.375 3.59375 -3.3125 C 3.59375 -3.25 3.578125 -3.1875 3.5625 -3.140625 Z M 3.078125 -1.1875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.375 -6.8125 C 2.375 -6.8125 2.375 -6.921875 2.25 -6.921875 C 2.03125 -6.921875 1.296875 -6.84375 1.03125 -6.8125 C 0.953125 -6.8125 0.84375 -6.796875 0.84375 -6.625 C 0.84375 -6.5 0.9375 -6.5 1.09375 -6.5 C 1.5625 -6.5 1.578125 -6.4375 1.578125 -6.328125 C 1.578125 -6.265625 1.5 -5.921875 1.453125 -5.71875 L 0.625 -2.46875 C 0.515625 -1.96875 0.46875 -1.796875 0.46875 -1.453125 C 0.46875 -0.515625 1 0.109375 1.734375 0.109375 C 2.90625 0.109375 4.140625 -1.375 4.140625 -2.8125 C 4.140625 -3.71875 3.609375 -4.40625 2.8125 -4.40625 C 2.359375 -4.40625 1.9375 -4.109375 1.640625 -3.8125 Z M 1.453125 -3.046875 C 1.5 -3.265625 1.5 -3.28125 1.59375 -3.390625 C 2.078125 -4.03125 2.53125 -4.1875 2.796875 -4.1875 C 3.15625 -4.1875 3.421875 -3.890625 3.421875 -3.25 C 3.421875 -2.65625 3.09375 -1.515625 2.90625 -1.140625 C 2.578125 -0.46875 2.125 -0.109375 1.734375 -0.109375 C 1.390625 -0.109375 1.0625 -0.375 1.0625 -1.109375 C 1.0625 -1.3125 1.0625 -1.5 1.21875 -2.125 Z M 1.453125 -3.046875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph2-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph2-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.515625 -1.265625 L 3.28125 -1.265625 C 3.265625 -1.109375 3.1875 -0.703125 3.09375 -0.640625 C 3.046875 -0.59375 2.515625 -0.59375 2.40625 -0.59375 L 1.125 -0.59375 C 1.859375 -1.234375 2.109375 -1.4375 2.515625 -1.765625 C 3.03125 -2.171875 3.515625 -2.609375 3.515625 -3.265625 C 3.515625 -4.109375 2.78125 -4.625 1.890625 -4.625 C 1.03125 -4.625 0.4375 -4.015625 0.4375 -3.375 C 0.4375 -3.03125 0.734375 -2.984375 0.8125 -2.984375 C 0.96875 -2.984375 1.171875 -3.109375 1.171875 -3.359375 C 1.171875 -3.484375 1.125 -3.734375 0.765625 -3.734375 C 0.984375 -4.21875 1.453125 -4.375 1.78125 -4.375 C 2.484375 -4.375 2.84375 -3.828125 2.84375 -3.265625 C 2.84375 -2.65625 2.40625 -2.1875 2.1875 -1.9375 L 0.515625 -0.265625 C 0.4375 -0.203125 0.4375 -0.1875 0.4375 0 L 3.3125 0 Z M 3.515625 -1.265625 "/>
</symbol>
</g>
</defs>
<g id="surface1">
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="-0.344" y="9.72"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="3.53" y="9.72"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-2" x="11.01" y="9.72"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph1-2" x="20.973" y="9.72"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-3" x="25.248" y="9.72"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph2-1" x="29.123" y="5.606"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

**step 2**:i then took svg code of 1/2(a+b)^2 and inserted in html page.
***but this svg is not rendering properly***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40pt" height="21pt" viewBox="0 0 40 21" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.9375 -6.375 C 2.9375 -6.625 2.9375 -6.640625 2.703125 -6.640625 C 2.078125 -6 1.203125 -6 0.890625 -6 L 0.890625 -5.6875 C 1.09375 -5.6875 1.671875 -5.6875 2.1875 -5.953125 L 2.1875 -0.78125 C 2.1875 -0.421875 2.15625 -0.3125 1.265625 -0.3125 L 0.953125 -0.3125 L 0.953125 0 C 1.296875 -0.03125 2.15625 -0.03125 2.5625 -0.03125 C 2.953125 -0.03125 3.828125 -0.03125 4.171875 0 L 4.171875 -0.3125 L 3.859375 -0.3125 C 2.953125 -0.3125 2.9375 -0.421875 2.9375 -0.78125 Z M 2.9375 -6.375 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 1.265625 -0.765625 L 2.328125 -1.796875 C 3.875 -3.171875 4.46875 -3.703125 4.46875 -4.703125 C 4.46875 -5.84375 3.578125 -6.640625 2.359375 -6.640625 C 1.234375 -6.640625 0.5 -5.71875 0.5 -4.828125 C 0.5 -4.28125 1 -4.28125 1.03125 -4.28125 C 1.203125 -4.28125 1.546875 -4.390625 1.546875 -4.8125 C 1.546875 -5.0625 1.359375 -5.328125 1.015625 -5.328125 C 0.9375 -5.328125 0.921875 -5.328125 0.890625 -5.3125 C 1.109375 -5.96875 1.65625 -6.328125 2.234375 -6.328125 C 3.140625 -6.328125 3.5625 -5.515625 3.5625 -4.703125 C 3.5625 -3.90625 3.078125 -3.125 2.515625 -2.5 L 0.609375 -0.375 C 0.5 -0.265625 0.5 -0.234375 0.5 0 L 4.203125 0 L 4.46875 -1.734375 L 4.234375 -1.734375 C 4.171875 -1.4375 4.109375 -1 4 -0.84375 C 3.9375 -0.765625 3.28125 -0.765625 3.0625 -0.765625 Z M 1.265625 -0.765625 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-3">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.296875 2.390625 C 3.296875 2.359375 3.296875 2.34375 3.125 2.171875 C 1.890625 0.921875 1.5625 -0.96875 1.5625 -2.5 C 1.5625 -4.234375 1.9375 -5.96875 3.171875 -7.203125 C 3.296875 -7.328125 3.296875 -7.34375 3.296875 -7.375 C 3.296875 -7.453125 3.265625 -7.484375 3.203125 -7.484375 C 3.09375 -7.484375 2.203125 -6.796875 1.609375 -5.53125 C 1.109375 -4.4375 0.984375 -3.328125 0.984375 -2.5 C 0.984375 -1.71875 1.09375 -0.515625 1.640625 0.625 C 2.25 1.84375 3.09375 2.5 3.203125 2.5 C 3.265625 2.5 3.296875 2.46875 3.296875 2.390625 Z M 3.296875 2.390625 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-4">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.078125 -2.296875 L 6.859375 -2.296875 C 7 -2.296875 7.1875 -2.296875 7.1875 -2.5 C 7.1875 -2.6875 7 -2.6875 6.859375 -2.6875 L 4.078125 -2.6875 L 4.078125 -5.484375 C 4.078125 -5.625 4.078125 -5.8125 3.875 -5.8125 C 3.671875 -5.8125 3.671875 -5.625 3.671875 -5.484375 L 3.671875 -2.6875 L 0.890625 -2.6875 C 0.75 -2.6875 0.5625 -2.6875 0.5625 -2.5 C 0.5625 -2.296875 0.75 -2.296875 0.890625 -2.296875 L 3.671875 -2.296875 L 3.671875 0.5 C 3.671875 0.640625 3.671875 0.828125 3.875 0.828125 C 4.078125 0.828125 4.078125 0.640625 4.078125 0.5 Z M 4.078125 -2.296875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-5">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.875 -2.5 C 2.875 -3.265625 2.765625 -4.46875 2.21875 -5.609375 C 1.625 -6.828125 0.765625 -7.484375 0.671875 -7.484375 C 0.609375 -7.484375 0.5625 -7.4375 0.5625 -7.375 C 0.5625 -7.34375 0.5625 -7.328125 0.75 -7.140625 C 1.734375 -6.15625 2.296875 -4.578125 2.296875 -2.5 C 2.296875 -0.78125 1.9375 0.96875 0.703125 2.21875 C 0.5625 2.34375 0.5625 2.359375 0.5625 2.390625 C 0.5625 2.453125 0.609375 2.5 0.671875 2.5 C 0.765625 2.5 1.671875 1.8125 2.25 0.546875 C 2.765625 -0.546875 2.875 -1.65625 2.875 -2.5 Z M 2.875 -2.5 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.71875 -3.765625 C 3.53125 -4.140625 3.25 -4.40625 2.796875 -4.40625 C 1.640625 -4.40625 0.40625 -2.9375 0.40625 -1.484375 C 0.40625 -0.546875 0.953125 0.109375 1.71875 0.109375 C 1.921875 0.109375 2.421875 0.0625 3.015625 -0.640625 C 3.09375 -0.21875 3.453125 0.109375 3.921875 0.109375 C 4.28125 0.109375 4.5 -0.125 4.671875 -0.4375 C 4.828125 -0.796875 4.96875 -1.40625 4.96875 -1.421875 C 4.96875 -1.53125 4.875 -1.53125 4.84375 -1.53125 C 4.75 -1.53125 4.734375 -1.484375 4.703125 -1.34375 C 4.53125 -0.703125 4.359375 -0.109375 3.953125 -0.109375 C 3.671875 -0.109375 3.65625 -0.375 3.65625 -0.5625 C 3.65625 -0.78125 3.671875 -0.875 3.78125 -1.3125 C 3.890625 -1.71875 3.90625 -1.828125 4 -2.203125 L 4.359375 -3.59375 C 4.421875 -3.875 4.421875 -3.890625 4.421875 -3.9375 C 4.421875 -4.109375 4.3125 -4.203125 4.140625 -4.203125 C 3.890625 -4.203125 3.75 -3.984375 3.71875 -3.765625 Z M 3.078125 -1.1875 C 3.015625 -1 3.015625 -0.984375 2.875 -0.8125 C 2.4375 -0.265625 2.03125 -0.109375 1.75 -0.109375 C 1.25 -0.109375 1.109375 -0.65625 1.109375 -1.046875 C 1.109375 -1.546875 1.421875 -2.765625 1.65625 -3.234375 C 1.96875 -3.8125 2.40625 -4.1875 2.8125 -4.1875 C 3.453125 -4.1875 3.59375 -3.375 3.59375 -3.3125 C 3.59375 -3.25 3.578125 -3.1875 3.5625 -3.140625 Z M 3.078125 -1.1875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.375 -6.8125 C 2.375 -6.8125 2.375 -6.921875 2.25 -6.921875 C 2.03125 -6.921875 1.296875 -6.84375 1.03125 -6.8125 C 0.953125 -6.8125 0.84375 -6.796875 0.84375 -6.625 C 0.84375 -6.5 0.9375 -6.5 1.09375 -6.5 C 1.5625 -6.5 1.578125 -6.4375 1.578125 -6.328125 C 1.578125 -6.265625 1.5 -5.921875 1.453125 -5.71875 L 0.625 -2.46875 C 0.515625 -1.96875 0.46875 -1.796875 0.46875 -1.453125 C 0.46875 -0.515625 1 0.109375 1.734375 0.109375 C 2.90625 0.109375 4.140625 -1.375 4.140625 -2.8125 C 4.140625 -3.71875 3.609375 -4.40625 2.8125 -4.40625 C 2.359375 -4.40625 1.9375 -4.109375 1.640625 -3.8125 Z M 1.453125 -3.046875 C 1.5 -3.265625 1.5 -3.28125 1.59375 -3.390625 C 2.078125 -4.03125 2.53125 -4.1875 2.796875 -4.1875 C 3.15625 -4.1875 3.421875 -3.890625 3.421875 -3.25 C 3.421875 -2.65625 3.09375 -1.515625 2.90625 -1.140625 C 2.578125 -0.46875 2.125 -0.109375 1.734375 -0.109375 C 1.390625 -0.109375 1.0625 -0.375 1.0625 -1.109375 C 1.0625 -1.3125 1.0625 -1.5 1.21875 -2.125 Z M 1.453125 -3.046875 "/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph2-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
</symbol>
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph2-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.515625 -1.265625 L 3.28125 -1.265625 C 3.265625 -1.109375 3.1875 -0.703125 3.09375 -0.640625 C 3.046875 -0.59375 2.515625 -0.59375 2.40625 -0.59375 L 1.125 -0.59375 C 1.859375 -1.234375 2.109375 -1.4375 2.515625 -1.765625 C 3.03125 -2.171875 3.515625 -2.609375 3.515625 -3.265625 C 3.515625 -4.109375 2.78125 -4.625 1.890625 -4.625 C 1.03125 -4.625 0.4375 -4.015625 0.4375 -3.375 C 0.4375 -3.03125 0.734375 -2.984375 0.8125 -2.984375 C 0.96875 -2.984375 1.171875 -3.109375 1.171875 -3.359375 C 1.171875 -3.484375 1.125 -3.734375 0.765625 -3.734375 C 0.984375 -4.21875 1.453125 -4.375 1.78125 -4.375 C 2.484375 -4.375 2.84375 -3.828125 2.84375 -3.265625 C 2.84375 -2.65625 2.40625 -2.1875 2.1875 -1.9375 L 0.515625 -0.265625 C 0.4375 -0.203125 0.4375 -0.1875 0.4375 0 L 3.3125 0 Z M 3.515625 -1.265625 "/>
</symbol>
</g>
</defs>
<g id="surface1">
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="0.165" y="7.181"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.398;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M -0.0009375 0.0003125 L 4.979531 0.0003125 " transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0.165,11.43)"/>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-2" x="0.165" y="20.755"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-3" x="6.342" y="13.921"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="10.216" y="13.921"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="17.696" y="13.921"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph1-2" x="27.659" y="13.921"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph0-5" x="31.935" y="13.921"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xlink:href="#glyph2-1" x="35.809" y="9.808"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks OK to me, what exactly do you think is wrong with it. Note that you can't put them both inline on the same page as they share id values which is not allowed.

Comment: As Robert Longson said, you have to use different IDs and your problem is going to be fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/5p0v11rt/2/

You may have to figure out another way for reusabilty.

Comment: thank you Robert Longson and MajeStic for helping.